# Oracle combine where condition in a view

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

i have following query:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1 where col2 = 'value'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1
FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 FROM table1 where col2 = 'value')
```

what this does is it checks col2 condition in the table1 first, if there's no rows it returns the data from table2.

i want to convert this into a view so that i can run the following query and get the same results:

```
select col1 from my_view where col2='value'
```

is this possible or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: well `create view ` for the select ?

Comment: @Moudiz it's not possible because where condition exist in two places

Comment: Are you missing `col2 = 'value'` in the where clause of table2?

Comment: @AsankaSenavirathna . . . If I understand what you are asking for, then you cannot quite do this with a view.  You need a function that returns a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you want, although it is not exactly what you asked for (missing `col2 = 'value'` in the second part of your query?):

```sql
SELECT col1, col2 
  FROM TABLE1 a
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM TABLE2 b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = b.col2)
```

Comment: I think this does what the OP wants.  The one caveat is that it might not optimize very well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the oracle documentation on how to [create views](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj15446.html).

```
CREATE VIEW my_view ("col1", "col2") AS
SELECT col1
FROM table1 where col2 = 'value'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1
FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 FROM table1 where col2 = 'value')
```